# Why does the nspawn of an ubuntu image fail?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, virtual-machine, container, systemd-nspawn

I would like to `systemd-nspawn` an Ubuntu image (yakkety, the host is on yakkety as well). This used to work without problems, so I guess something changed in the last ~6 months.

I created an image via `debootstrap`:

```
# debootstrap --variant=minbase --include=nano,dbus,isc-dhcp-client,iputils-ping,iproute2,python3 yakkety yakkety http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

I then tried to start it:

```
# machinectl start yakkety
```

There was no error message but the container did not start. `journalctl -xe` exposed the error:

```
Feb 27 13:24:27 srv systemd-nspawn[27348]: execv(/usr/lib/systemd/systemd, /lib/systemd/systemd, /sbin/init) failed: No such file or directory
```

**It looks like there is nothing to initialize?** How is that possible with an image created via `debootstrap`? The image looks normal otherwise (it contains usual folders and binaries - except the ones above which could not be started as they are absent)

A direct call to`systemd-nspawn` yields the same error:

```
# systemd-nspawn -b -D yakkety -n
Spawning container yakkety on /var/lib/machines/yakkety.
Press ^] three times within 1s to kill container.
execv(/usr/lib/systemd/systemd, /lib/systemd/systemd, /sbin/init) failed: No such file or directory
Container yakkety failed with error code 1.
```

I tried to recreate the image by adding the `systemd` and `init` packages to the luist of packages to be preinstalled (after `python3` in my example above) but this did not chnage anything.

**What is the problem?** Are there extra packages I need to install? (I did not install anything special previously for `xenial` and, if I am not mistaken, neither for `yakkety`).

All packages are attheir latest version, including `systemd` (233).

Answer (score 1):

You need to install an init system inside your container, for example systemd:

```
chroot /var/lib/machines/yakkety
apt-get install systemd
```

I had the same problem on Debian and this fixed the problem.